# CSS Flexbox - Centrar todos los elementos hijos con altura completa relativa al elemento padre

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Necesito alinear todos los elementos hijos, con altura completa relativa al elemento principal.

Todo está bien hasta que uso la propiedad **align-items: center;** , los elementos se alinean completamente, pero no cubren el 100% de la altura, y si uso **align-self: stretch;** cubre el 100% pero no alinea los elementos verticalmente, hay alguna solución para esto.

```css
.abouts {
  display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.abouts .item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="abouts">
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content height...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Vision</h3>
    <p>Content here details, more content for test equal height all elements more content for test equal height all elements...</p>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
</div>
```

Comment: Si eliminas `flex: 1;` funciona.

Comment: Los necesito alineados todos con el fondo también, la misma altura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quité el justify y el center. Pero no estoy seguro si era esto lo que querías.

Por lo pronto tienen la misma altura y están alineados arriba.

```css
.abouts {
  display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 1;
 
}

.abouts .item-wrapper {
  width:33%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  
}

.item {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="abouts">
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Vision</h3>
      <p>Content here details, more content height...</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Vision</h3>
      <p>Content here details...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
  
  <!-- ITEM -->
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Vision</h3>
      <p>Content here details, more content for test equal height all elements more content for test equal height all elements...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ ITEM -->
</div>
```

Comment: Pero el contenido no esta centrado verticalmente, eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias.